# How to set a default width to a header cell html

Tags: html, css

I'm using aspnet mvc and rendering a header cell and the elements inside of loop, for every header there's a element. The result is

[image]

But the problem is, if one of the items does not have more headers or elements the header line stops at the end and What I want is, make that line go until the end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS, you can just put in `width: 100%`.

Comment: where ? the table or each th ?

Comment: @NathielPaulino try different combinations of them and see what works